# TV show with a small trouble-making protagonist with wings and a pet

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a show with three human characters and a big pet of one of the humans with blacksmith kind of clothing (I think). There was also a mother figure (or there was mention of the mother) and the main person was small, was also was a trouble maker, and lived within castle walls in a maybe rundown looking house.  The main thing I remember is that the main person went out of the castle walls to go find adventure with them having wings as well and the pet saving the main person.

I think it was a 3D animated show with sci-fi fantasy elements to it.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to further improve it with details. When did you watch this? In what country? What was the animation style? Was there adult humor? What did the pet look like? What was the skin color of the protagonist? :) The more details you can provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: What do you mean by "3D animated" ?

Comment: @KeithMcClary You know, like [this](https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F6%2F2018%2F10%2Fsimpsons-2-2000.jpg&q=85)

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Disenchantment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenchantment_(TV_series)) from the creator of the Simpsons?

It is cell-shaded, so 3D graphics rendered to look like a hand drawn cartoon.

[Disenchantment Main Characters](https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/disenchantment-2.jpg?w=1024)